# Add logo to slidy_presentation in RMarkdown in header

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, presentation

I'd like to add a logo in the background of my presentation for instance in the top rigth corner.
Take for instance this example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "23/07/2020"
output:
   slidy_presentation:
    css: styles.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.
````

With this logo

[image]

style.css:

```
.title-slide {
 background-image: url("logo1.png");
}
```

The end results should look like this:
[image]

I am aware of [these examples](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/slidify-logo/) but none of this works despite having installed everything.
For instance,

```
logo : logo1.PNG
biglogo : logo1.PNG
```

does not work. The examples don't work even when I download them from the website.